# Why the IRtcEngine instance is not created?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

i'm trying to implement a voice chat in my Unity game using agora.io. I followed the official start up tutorials and I put the code below in a script attached to an empty Gameobject in the scene:
[My simple start up script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMW1l.png)

So, at the Start, the IRtcEngine instance should be created as I call the IRtcEngine.GetEngine(agoraAppID) method. The problem is that, instead od returnig the instance, this method prints an error log: "Create engine failed, error code: -7"

I looked up what the error code 7 means: "A method is called before the initialization of RtcEngine. Ensure that the RtcEngineinstance is created and initialized before calling the method".
So I tried commenting everything but the line in which the IRtcEngine.GetEngine(agoraAppID) method is called, but the error still pops up. It pops up even when I play the agora demo scene "HelloUnity".

I also tried removing the agora package and importing it again. It worked because after that the instance was created correctly, but after a few times, the error started popping up again.

Unity version: 2020.3.3f1

Agora version: 3.3.1.71

What could the problem be? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same error code. Closing all Unity instances and rebooting my computer was helped me.

Usually, it happens if you don't leave the channel properly. So, putting

> rtcEngine?.LeaveChannel()

to

> OnDestroy()

may be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

should look something like this.  don't forget the variable declaration up top.

```
public class Launch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IRtcEngine mRtcEngine;

    void Start()
    {
        string agoraAccountId = "4ca78bc86f23hhhhhhhhh4444444444";
        
        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Agora engine exists already!!");
            return;
        }
        mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.GetEngine(agoraAccountId);
```

I suggest you join the Agora slack channel (it is easy to join) where you can get answers quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Demo project code and watch out how the sample app handles the life cycle in Unity.  In your simple script, there is no clean up code on destroy.  You left certain socket/ports open on the system. That's why when you get some success on a fresh install but not the subsequent run.